# sqlserver - case in the where

Tags: sql, sql-server

My aim is to have the equivalent of this

```
SELECT CFE_DIR_PMOR.col1,CFE_DIR_PMOR.col2,CFE_DIR_PMOR.col3
    FROM CFE_DIR_PMOR INNER JOIN CFE_DIR_PPHY 
    WHERE <cdt1> AND <cdt2> ... AND <cdt5>
    AND CFE_DIR_PMOR.GESTDEL IS NULL
    AND CFE_DIR_PPHY.GESTDEL = '1'
UNION ALL
SELECT CFE_DIR_PMOR.col1,CFE_DIR_PMOR.col2,CFE_DIR_PMOR.col3
    FROM table1
    WHERE <cdt1> AND <cdt2> ... AND <cdt5>
    AND CFE_DIR_PMOR.GESTDEL = '1'
    AND CFE_DIR_PPHY.GESTDEL IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT CFE_DIR_PMOR.col1,CFE_DIR_PMOR.col2,CFE_DIR_PMOR.col3
    FROM table1
    WHERE <cdt1> AND <cdt2> ... AND <cdt5>
    AND CFE_DIR_PMOR.GESTDEL = '1'
    AND CFE_DIR_PPHY.GESTDEL = '1'
    AND CFE_DIR_PMOR.rep_legal= '1'
UNION ALL
SELECT CFE_DIR_PMOR.col1,CFE_DIR_PMOR.col2,CFE_DIR_PMOR.col3
    FROM table1
    WHERE <cdt1> AND <cdt2> ... AND <cdt5>
    AND CFE_DIR_PMOR.GESTDEL = '1'
    AND CFE_DIR_PPHY.GESTDEL = '1'
    AND CFE_DIR_PMOR.rep_legal != 1
    AND CFE_DIR_PPHY.ORDRE = '00'
```

As you can see, it is burdensome and a CASE in the WHERE can be a good solution. So this is what I did

```
SELECT CFE_DIR_PMOR.col1,CFE_DIR_PMOR.col2,CFE_DIR_PMOR.col3
    FROM table1
    WHERE <cdt1> AND <cdt2> ... AND <cdt5>
AND
    CASE WHEN CFE_DIR_PMOR.GESTDEL IS NULL AND CFE_DIR_PPHY.GESTDEL = '1' THEN 1
     WHEN CFE_DIR_PMOR.GESTDEL = '1' AND CFE_DIR_PPHY.GESTDEL IS NULL THEN 1
     ELSE
      CASE WHEN CFE_DIR_PMOR.GESTDEL = '1' AND CFE_DIR_PPHY.GESTDEL = '1' AND CFE_DIR_PMOR.rep_legal= 1 THEN 1 
           WHEN CFE_DIR_PMOR.GESTDEL = '1' AND CFE_DIR_PPHY.GESTDEL = '1' AND CFE_DIR_PMOR.rep_legal != 1 AND CFE_DIR_PPHY.ORDRE = '00' THEN 1
           ELSE 0
      END
          END =1
```

Question:

- Is my case done correctly? if no, are there anything missing

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `case` expressions in the `where` clause, use `and`/`or` instead.

Comment: @jarlh why?, do you have any links to explain that comment?

Comment: your where clause isn't comparing anything to the boolean return of case. You need something like `where column = case when ....then... end = 1`

Comment: hi @jarlh how can I rewrite that? Do you have any examples?

Comment: hi @scsimon do you have any ideas or examples?

Comment: @AndyK And yes, your `CASE` expression seems equivalent to your first query. But there's no need for using `ELSE CASE...`, you could just keep using `WHEN`

Comment: @scsimon the query does have an `= 1` at the end

Comment: @Lamak yes, i know.

Comment: hi @Lamak if you have any ideas, I'm all ears

Comment: @scsimon sooo, what was your comment about?

Comment: guys, don't get into a verbal-sql fight, otherwise i'm `drop` the question (wink wink - sql joke)

Comment: Althoug you can rewrite the query, UNION ALL may have better perfomance then OR in WHERE

Comment: Hi @Serg the query is very big that's why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `OR`

```
SELECT CFE_DIR_PMOR.col1,CFE_DIR_PMOR.col2,CFE_DIR_PMOR.col3
FROM CFE_DIR_PMOR INNER JOIN CFE_DIR_PPHY 
ON CFE_DIR_PMOR.[Something] = CFE_DIR_PPHY.[Something]
WHERE <cdt1> AND <cdt2> ... AND <cdt5>
AND ((CFE_DIR_PMOR.GESTDEL IS NULL
    AND CFE_DIR_PPHY.GESTDEL = '1')
OR (CFE_DIR_PMOR.GESTDEL = '1'
    AND CFE_DIR_PPHY.GESTDEL IS NULL )
OR (CFE_DIR_PMOR.GESTDEL = '1'
    AND CFE_DIR_PPHY.GESTDEL = '1'
    AND CFE_DIR_PMOR.rep_legal= '1')
OR (CFE_DIR_PMOR.GESTDEL = '1'
    AND CFE_DIR_PPHY.GESTDEL = '1'
    AND CFE_DIR_PMOR.rep_legal != 1
    AND CFE_DIR_PPHY.ORDRE = '00'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want `case` in the `where`, when `or` would do:

```
SELECT CFE_DIR_PMOR.col1,CFE_DIR_PMOR.col2,CFE_DIR_PMOR.col3
FROM CFE_DIR_PMOR INNER JOIN
     CFE_DIR_PPHY 
     ON ??
WHERE <cdt1> AND <cdt2> ... AND <cdt5> AND
      ( (CFE_DIR_PMOR.GESTDEL IS NULL AND CFE_DIR_PPHY.GESTDEL = '1') OR
        (CFE_DIR_PMOR.GESTDEL = '1' AND CFE_DIR_PPHY.GESTDEL IS NULL) OR
        . . .
      );
```

In addition, if you are using `JOIN`, you should have an `ON` clause.  I'm not sure which conditions go there.

Answer (score 2):

Using some logic to reduce the number of `OR`s which can slow a query way down

```
SELECT CFE_DIR_PMOR.col1,CFE_DIR_PMOR.col2,CFE_DIR_PMOR.col3
    FROM Table1
    WHERE <cdt1> AND <cdt2> ... AND <cdt5>
     AND
     (cast((isnull(@id2,'')+isnull(@id,'')) as int)=1)
     OR
     ((CFE_DIR_PMOR.GESTDEL = '1'AND CFE_DIR_PPHY.GESTDEL = '1')
       AND
     (CFE_DIR_PMOR.rep_legal= '1' OR CFE_DIR_PPHY.ORDRE = '00'))
```

Is Table1 the same as the `Inner Join` you want perform?

Answer (score 1):

```
  **Combined common filters from the last two case statements**
  SELECT CFE_DIR_PMOR.col1,CFE_DIR_PMOR.col2,CFE_DIR_PMOR.col3
    FROM 
    CFE_DIR_PMOR INNER JOIN CFE_DIR_PPHY 
    ON CFE_DIR_PMOR.[Column] = CFE_DIR_PPHY.[Matching Column]
    WHERE <cdt1> AND <cdt2> ... AND <cdt5>
    AND 
    (
        (CFE_DIR_PMOR.GESTDEL IS NULL AND
             CFE_DIR_PPHY.GESTDEL = '1')
        OR 
        (CFE_DIR_PMOR.GESTDEL = '1' AND
             CFE_DIR_PPHY.GESTDEL IS NULL )
        OR 
        (
                (CFE_DIR_PMOR.GESTDEL = '1' AND
                 CFE_DIR_PPHY.GESTDEL = '1')
            AND
            ( 
                (CFE_DIR_PMOR.rep_legal= '1') 
                0R
                (CFE_DIR_PMOR.rep_legal != 1
                    AND CFE_DIR_PPHY.ORDRE = '00')
            )
        )
    )
```